# Excel VBA copying rows to another sheet that contains the value found in a specific column

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook for our projects that has a Master Sheet that contains all the doors/products for that job. In Column BF contains the number for the stage delivery that product is on. I have got this working correctly (see below) to copy each row containing a product to the sheet for that stage. These are named like this: "Stage 1 Sheet", "Stage 2 Sheet". I have this working for if there are only the two stage deliveries. I want it to do up to about 24 stages.

The problem I have is that my code is going to be very long. Is there a way it can match the value in the stage column to the number on the Stage sheets?
Here is my code:

```
Sub LineCopy()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 10 To LR
    If Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("BF" & i).Value = "1" Then
        Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Stage 1 Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    ElseIf Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("BF" & i).Value = "2" Then
        Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Stage 2 Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    End If
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

This is the layout of my sheets. I will be adding more sheets for up to 24 stages/deliveries:

[image]

I have more I want to add to this code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to introduce a **second FOR Loop** within the loop:

```
Dim LR As Long, i As Long, x As Long
LR = Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


For i = 10 To LR
    For x = 1 To 24
        If Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("BF" & i).Value = x Then
            Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets("Stage " & x & " Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        End If
    Next x
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you so much. I've been trying to do something like that but for some reason it just wouldn't work. Is it possible to add to that so that if it finds a stage number that it can't find the corresponding Stage sheet to, it copies an original stage sheet(that I'll add) and rename it to the new stage number, then copies the products for that stage?

Comment: Sorry, I am not following. You trying to add the original stage sheet if the value is not between 1 and 24? What do you mean by original stage sheet?

Comment: Some jobs have 2 staged deliveries and others have 23 or 24. I was thinking that rather than having all those tabs there I could create an 'Original Stage Sheet' which the macro could copy and rename according to the number of stages/deliveries for that particular job. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that is definitely possible, but it is a new problem and therefore should be addressed separately. I would create an 'Original Stage Sheet', try to embed it into the code and if you struggle ask this in separate question.

Comment: Btw, if my answer above was helpful don't forget to tick the answer check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: No worries, glad to help.